# Installing Tomcat 8.* in a docker container with Centos 7

Tags: docker, tomcat, tomcat8

I want to create a docker container to install Tomcat within it. It seems that my docker compiles with no problem and I am also able to run tomcat with no problems reported through the logs. Yet, if I try to open tomcat I get a 404 error. I do not know what I am missing. Any ideas, please? The next is the content of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:7
MAINTAINER joseccz

EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8009


RUN yum install -y mc
RUN yum install -y wget
# RUN yum install -y apr-devel openssl-devel
RUN yum install -y gcc
RUN yum install epel-release -y
RUN yum install dnf -y
RUN yum install net-tools -y
RUN yum install libtool -y

ENV JAVA_HOME       /opt/javaSDK
ENV JRE_HOME        ${JAVA_HOME}/jre

ADD javaSDK ${JAVA_HOME}

ADD tomcat.service /etc/systemd/system/




# ----------------------------------------------- Copy Tomcat Files to /opt/tomcat -----------------------------------------------
ENV TOMCAT_MAJOR 8
ENV TOMCAT_VERSION 8.5.45
ENV CATALINA_HOME   /opt/tomcat

# http://www-us.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.45/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.45.tar.gz

ENV PATH        $JAVA_HOME/bin:$CATALINA_HOME/bin:$CATALINA_HOME/lib:$PATH

RUN wget http://www-us.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-${TOMCAT_MAJOR}/v${TOMCAT_VERSION}/bin/apache-tomcat-${TOMCAT_VERSION}.tar.gz && \
 tar -xvf apache-tomcat-${TOMCAT_VERSION}.tar.gz 

RUN mv apache-tomcat-${TOMCAT_VERSION} tomcat

RUN rm apache-tomcat*.tar.gz
RUN mv tomcat /opt/tomcat
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



RUN groupadd tomcat
RUN useradd -s /bin/nologin -g tomcat -d /opt/tomcat tomcat

# RUN wget https://rpmfind.net/linux/mageia/distrib/cauldron/x86_64/media/core/release/tomcat-native-1.2.23-1.mga8.x86_64.rpm
# RUN rpm -i tomcat-native-1.2.23-1.mga8.x86_64.rpm

# RUN cd /opt/tomcat
RUN chgrp -R tomcat /opt/tomcat/conf
RUN chmod g+rwx /opt/tomcat/conf
RUN chmod g+r /opt/tomcat/conf/*
RUN chown -R tomcat /opt/tomcat/logs/ /opt/tomcat/temp/ /opt/tomcat/webapps/ /opt/tomcat/work/

RUN chgrp -R tomcat /opt/tomcat/bin
RUN chgrp -R tomcat /opt/tomcat/lib
RUN chmod g+rwx /opt/tomcat/bin
RUN chmod g+r /opt/tomcat/bin/*

#----------------------------------Create /opt/software folder for addinitonal soft needed by Tomcat ------------------------------
RUN mkdir /opt/software

#---------------------------------------- copy and compile Development tools ---------------------------------------------------------

RUN yum groupinstall "Development Tools" -y

#---------------------------------------- Donwload and install open ssl ------------------------------------------------------------
RUN wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2l.tar.gz
RUN tar -xvf openssl-1.0.2l.tar.gz
RUN mv openssl-1.0.2l openssl
RUN mv openssl /opt/software/openssl
RUN cd /opt/software/openssl && ./config -fPIC --prefix=/opt/software/ --openssldir=/opt/software/ && make && make install

#---------------------------------------- Donwload and install open apr ------------------------------------------------------------
ENV APRVERSION 1.6.5
RUN wget http://apache.mirrors.ionfish.org//apr/apr-${APRVERSION}.tar.gz
RUN tar -xvf apr-${APRVERSION}.tar.gz
RUN mv apr-${APRVERSION} apr
RUN mv apr /opt/software/apr
RUN cd /opt/software/apr/ && \
    ./configure --prefix=/opt/software/ && \
     make && make install

#------------------------------------------ Copy TOMCAT native


# compiling tomcat native

RUN cd ${CATALINA_HOME}/bin/ && \
    tar -xvf tomcat-native.tar.gz && \
    cd tomcat-native-1.2.23-src/native/ && \
     ./configure --with-apr=/opt/software/ --with-java-home=/opt/javaSDK/  --with-ssl=/opt/software  --prefix=/opt/tomcat && \
    make && \
    make install

ADD setenv.sh /opt/tomcat/bin/
```

my setenv.sh file content is:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/javaSDK
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$CATALINA_HOME/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Does this installation work on a bare metal machine? I was considering repeating your steps, but if you solved it then I might not need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important part is to somehow add the next xommands to the dockerfile:

```
#---------------------------------------- Donwload and install open apr ------------------------------------------------------------
ENV APRVERSION 1.6.5
RUN wget http://apache.mirrors.ionfish.org//apr/apr-${APRVERSION}.tar.gz
RUN tar -xvf apr-${APRVERSION}.tar.gz
RUN mv apr-${APRVERSION} apr
RUN mv apr /opt/software/apr
RUN cd /opt/software/apr/ && \
    ./configure --prefix=/opt/software/ && \
     make && make install

#------------------------------------------ Copy TOMCAT native


# compiling tomcat native

RUN cd ${CATALINA_HOME}/bin/ && \
    tar -xvf tomcat-native.tar.gz && \
    cd tomcat-native-1.2.8-src/native/ && \
     ./configure --with-apr=/opt/software/ --with-java-home=/opt/javaSDK/ --with-ssl=/opt/software  --prefix=/opt/tomcat && \
    make && \
    make install

ADD setenv.sh /opt/tomcat/bin/
```

The tomcat-native.tar.gz must be the one included in the version of Tomcat to be installed which is included in the tomca installation compressed file.
Also, the Tomcat applications sample included in the installation file must be at least manually added to the Tomcat's webapps folder. I had problems doing this automatically.